# Drawing custom TextBox Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, themes

I found this code [here](http://pastebin.com/WYAXTfVe) which explains how to create custom controls. I have been using these controls as buttons, but now that I am beginning to understand the code a bit more, I would like to try and create a text box control using the same drawing techniques. I have been searching endlessly for some examples on the subject, but cannot find a single one. I don't understand how a textbox can be writable if a rectangle is being used to make it. Does anybody have any experience creating custom controls in C#? I would like for my textbox to be able to match the theme in the above link which is why it has to be custom made.

Comment: A TextBox is quite untrivial to recreate.  Which is why nobody does it.  A rectangle?  No, a Control, aka window.  TextRenderer.DrawText().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, at the beginning you should have in mind, that the implementation of new text box control is kinda complicate thing. It is necessary that you consider the following points:

1) What should your textbox do? How can the user interact with it? Which events do you necessarely throw?
2) How should you textbox be drawn? Is it a simple box with an outline or do you have elements which are different if the user gets interacted.

A good starting point for implementing your own textbox is to look how it works under the hood - in fact, you should start by referencing to samples which came from the DirectX and DirectDrawing area, one example is the following link (the sample is for c++, but the concepts are the same as used in windowsforms or wpf drawing):

http://www.uc-forum.com/forum/d3d-tutorials-and-source/65377-make-textbox-ingame-console-directx.html

a more direct sample (explaining howto extend an existing textbox) can be found here:
http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/

All in all, to achieve your goal try to extend the basic text box at the beginning and afterwards start with a component which is not that complicated, for example a simple checkbox. Go on and at the end you will be able to implement your own textbox control ;)